# Gremlin: Capturing both (or all) the elements in a union() with as() - to then select() them later

Tags: select, union, gremlin

I can't work out how to capture/select the elements of a union in Gremlin. In this example, I'm trying to use `as()` to capture 'a' or 'b' and be able to tell (easily) which of the two it was that hit in `select()` step.

**Attempt 1:**

```
g.V().has('property', 'value').union(
    out().has('propertyA', 'valueA').as_('a'),
    out().has('propertyB', 'valueB').as_('b')
).select('a','b')
```

This gives no results, because we're trying to select *both* values, and they never *both* capture at the same time in the same result.

**Attempt 2:**

```
g.V().has('property', 'value').union(
    out().has('propertyA', 'valueA'),
    out().has('propertyB', 'valueB')
).as_('a_or_b').select('a_or_b')
```

This solves the no results problem, but doesn't let me work out which element of the union - was it 'a' or was it 'b'? - captured (without some post-processing).

Ideally, I want a result like `{a: [v100], b: []}` - if 'a' captured.

Note: this is a toy example. In the end it will need generalising and the 'a' and 'b' union elements might be arbitrarily complex.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use `union()` for some reason? Seems like you just need to `project()` you results:

```
g.V().has('property','value').
  filter(out().or(has('propertyA`,'valueA'),has('propertyB'),'valueB'))).
  project('a','b').
    by(out().has('propertyA','valueA').fold()).
    by(out().has('propertyB','valueB').fold())
```

That should give you the result you desired, but I'm not sure if I have the full context of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

I've tried a few things like that but the problem is the `by()` steps aren't compulsory - they don't *constrain* the results. I want my query to return *only* when there's a "property" vertex followed by a "propertyA" or "propertyB". But with the `by()` step, I get every "property" vertex in my data (assume there are thousands), with two empty lists (`{'a': [], 'b': []}`). How can I enforce that at least "a" or "b" hits?

Comment: updated my answer...you could filter the vertices you want up front i guess. might be a nicer way yet but that should solve the immediate problem you mention.